# Replace the beginning of every line of a possibly multiline pattern

Tags: perl, substitution

I'm trying to match a multiline pattern and modify every line matching this pattern including, the first one, so that a character will be added at the beginning of the line (`+/-`)

For example, I have that :

```
stuff above
<span>one-liner span</span>
stuff middle
    <span>stuff inside
    other stuff
    </span>
stuff below
```

And I want to obtain that :

```
stuff above
+ <span>one-liner span</span>
stuff middle
+     <span>stuff inside
+     other stuff
+     </span>
stuff below
```

So far I am there :

```
perl -n0e 's/\n(.*<span style="color: green".*?<\/span>)/+$1/g && print' myfile.html
```

The problem here is that it only modifies the first line and if it is a multiline pattern, I want to modify all the lines.

Any ideas how to do that ?

I'm using perl, but I'm open to other tools if you think it's better.

Thanks !

Comment: "_modify every line including the first one_"  --- but your "_want to obtain_" sample doesn't do that?  Do you mean the prefix all lines _within a `<span>` element_ in particular?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, I'll amend my question

Comment: In order to treat a scalar (presumably with newline chars in it) as a "truly" multiline string you want `/m` modifier, so that the beginning- and end- of line anchors match all linefeeds (and not only the beginning and end of the string). You often also want `/s` with which the `.` matches a newline as well.  However, needing to match only within a part of the string (inside `span` etc) will make this approach more complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

```
perl -wpe'print "+ " if /^\s*<span/ .. /<\/span>/' file
```

The `..` operator in this use maintains its state, so that

> Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.

Its typical use is precisely to select a range of lines, delimited by the given conditions.

Here I've restricted the opening `span`s to be the first non-blank thing on its line, but not the closing one so to allow for one-line `<span ...>word</span>` sections to work.

Comment: That's nice. I must add one requierement though, which I didn't mention before. The <span> tag may be only a one-liner. I think your code doesn't work for me for this situation because this will also be true for something like : `<span>.*</span>\n\nstuff\n</span>`. I will edit my question accordingly, sorry.

Comment: @ogr Do you mean that there may be `<span ...>red</span>` on one line? If that is so, all it took was to remove the `^` in the closing condition, so that `</span>` need not be on its own line.  I've added such one-line `span`, along with a few more lines, to your sample and it works.

Comment: Yep, it now seems to do the trick, thanks ! (I'm still pretty new to perl)

Comment: @ogr Great.  Let me know of questions, and/or if things come up later :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the range operator to mask the range you want, and then append to lines starting with white space. This code doesn't give exactly what you want but will point you in the right direction.

```
while(<>) {
    if( /stuff above/ .. /stuff below/ ){
        $_= "+".$_ if /^ +/;
        print $_;
    }
}
```

Range operator is one of my favourites!

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file

```
perl -ne 'if (/^\s*<(span)>.*?(<\/\1>)?\s*$/) {print "+$&";next if ($2);$t="</$1>";do{$_=<>;print "+$_"} until(/$t/) } else {print}' d
```

gnu sed

```
sed -E 's/<(span)>.*<\/\1>/+&/;Tc;b ;:c /^\s*<span>/{s/^/+/;:l n;s/^/+/;/<\/span>/!bl}' d
```